# redirect from one host to another

Tags: nginx

I have moved my site to another url. Now I want to forward the requests to the new url, this is what I have in my conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abc.domain.com;
  return 301 https://new.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Things to consider, I have other sites as well on my server; so I have multiple server blocks.
It works fine on chrome, but on firefox and edge it redirects everything else to new domain as well.

E.g on firefox, if I browse someothersite.domain.com, it will be redirected to new.domain.com. If I remove the above server block; it works fine.

Comment: You are redirecting from `http` to `https` at the same time. Do your other sites handle both requests over `http` and `https`?

Comment: @RichardSmith No. I have another generic server block, that listens to 80 and forward any requests to its corresponding https. Only for this specific abc.domain.com, I want it to be forwarded to https://new.domain.com